# less: do not display "filename (END)" at the end of page

Tags: shell, terminal, less, terminal-emulator

I need `less` to display a file without any additional formatting characters.

I found the `--tilde` option, which got rid of the `~` characters.

Now I only need to get rid of the:

```
(END)
```

or

```
<filename> (END)
```

at the and of the page.

I am happy to recompile `less` , if somebody can suggest what needs to be changed in the sourcecode.

I am using `less` 487 on Debian 10.

Comment: Is `less -E` not sufficient to your needs?

Comment: I know the answer to your earlier question doesn’t address this, but this is a duplicate.